# Sort data ASC priority to data not = 0

Tags: mysql

How to Seperate data = 0 from data not = 0, then sort data not = 0 ASC, and data = 0 at the last.

```
CREATE TABLE `fruit` (
`item` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`price` int(6) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
-- Dumping data for table `fruit`

INSERT INTO `fruit` (`item`, `type`, `price`) VALUES
('Apple', 'Grade A', 10),
('Apple', 'Grade B', 8),
('Banana', 'Grade A', 15),
('Banana', 'Grade B', 0),
('Banana', 'Grade C', 8),
('Mango', 'Grade A', 0),
('Mango', 'Grade B', 12);
-- Indexes for dumped tables
-- Indexes for table `fruit`

ALTER TABLE `fruit`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`item`,`type`) USING BTREE;
```

I try to sort by:

```
SELECT * FROM `fruit`
ORDER BY price DESC, item ASC
```

The result become:

```
('Banana', 'Grade A', 15),
('Mango',  'Grade B', 12),
('Apple',  'Grade A', 10),
('Apple',  'Grade B',  8),
('Banana', 'Grade C',  8),
('Banana', 'Grade B',  0),
('Mango',  'Grade A',  0),
```

Actuall I just want to push those price = 0 to that last, those prices which is not = 0 will follow primary index

I want result like this:

```
('Apple',  'Grade A', 10),
('Apple',  'Grade B',  8),
('Banana', 'Grade A', 15),
('Banana', 'Grade C',  8),
('Mango',  'Grade B', 12),
('Banana', 'Grade B',  0),
('Mango',  'Grade A',  0),
```

How can I do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use conditional `order by`. Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d75e5/5)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  SELECT * FROM `fruit`
    ORDER BY price=0,item asc
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `fruit`
ORDER BY if(price=0,0,1) DESC,price DESC, item ASC
```

Comment: No need to map logical values with expression - sql server can order by boolean values directly, so your expression is redundant

Comment: Sory, but the question is marked MYSQL, not SQL SERVER. Even so, the response is correct.

Comment: I know. I had in mind all relational database servers - not just microsoft sql server. Any decent relational database server should be able to sort by boolean value (as well as by any other computed expression)